# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'- sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone please tell what is wrong with the query

```
SET @TUYEN_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 
                    TUYEN_ID
                 FROM 
                    (SELECT TOP (@i) 
                        TUYEN_ID 
                     FROM 
                        @TUYENS 
                     ORDER BY 
                        TUYEN_ID ASC)
                 ORDER BY 
                    TUYEN_ID DESC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use aliases in your query:

```
SET @TUYEN_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 M.TUYEN_ID
                 FROM (SELECT TOP (@i) T.TUYEN_ID
                       FROM @TUYENS T
                       ORDER BY T.TUYEN_ID ASC) M
                 ORDER BY M.TUYEN_ID DESC)
```

Your `FROM` statement has no aliases for the result of the subquery, that probably causes an issue with the second `ORDER BY` clause.

Hope this will help

Comment: @VõVănMinh Nice to hear that! I suggest you to always use aliases in order to avoid such kind of issues/conflicts. It also increase the readability of complex queries